# Reset/Remove samrtTable filter on object

Tags: angularjs, filter, smart-table

I'm using SmartTable in AngularJS to display a list of records.

The problem is whenever user filter data by id, and select the row using checkbox, now again do the same but do not remove value searched in search text box then while submitting the data it only gives last one selected because object is filtered with that value. But I want all selected previous records too.

If we remove filter before submitting the form can solve the issue but don't know how to do that.

### Html code

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" st-table="employees">
<tr>
   <td>Select Column</td>
   <td>id <input st-search="id" class="input-sm form-control" type="search" placeholder="id" /></td> 
   <td>name</td> 
   <td>address</td> 
   <td>classA</td>
   <td>classB</td>
 </tr>  
<tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.checked"></td>
    <td>{{employee.id}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.address}}</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="employee.classA"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="employee.classB"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="button" name="save" value="submit" ng-click="submit()">
```

### JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.employees = [
        { id:"1", name: "A",              address: "A1",    classA: true,  classB: true  },
        { id:"2", name: "B",            address: "A2",    classA: false, classB: true  },
        { id:"3", name: "C",            address: "A3",    classA: true, classB: false  },
        { id:"4", name: "D",             address: "A4",   classA: false, classB: true  },
        { id:"5", name: "E",             address: "A5",   classA: false, classB: true  },
    ];  


  $scope.submit = = function () {
    var ar = $scope.employees.filter(
      function (value) {
        if (value.checked) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
    });
   // Selected Data
    console.log(ar);
  };


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** In your js file, change

`var app = angular.module('myApp', []);`

to

`var app = angular.module('myApp', ['smart-table']);`

you have forgotten to inject the `smart-table` module into your application.

**2.** In your HTML file change

`<input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.checked">`

to

`<input type="checkbox" ng-model="employee.checked">`

in your submit function you filter by the "checked" property in each employee object, not in a row object

**3.** you should realize that smart-table filters rows just as angular filters using normal `ng-repeat` with a filter. when you filter out a row in a table (or anything else in an ng-repeat) it's getting cut from your table as though you have applied it with `ng-if`, so if you select a row, then filter it, then click submit, your `console.log` function won't display the object because it's no longer a part of your table row collection.

to avoid this kind of situation, use the [stSafeSrc](http://plnkr.co/edit/WAvaES?p=preview) directive.

`<table st-table="displayedCollection" st-safe-src="rowCollection">`

"rowCollection" will hold a copy of the original data in memory while "displayedCollection" will be what you will see on the table on the view, then use filter+submit on that original data

Here is a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/WAvaES?p=preview) I've forked from your code that shows what I mean.